# Vue.js parent component event handler method can't access it's own data normally

Tags: javascript, arrays, events, vuejs2, vue-component

**what's happening in brief**

In the parent component, I am passing an array to a child component, and when the user selects one of the elements of that array, the child component emits an event, passing the selected item, which is handled in the parent. I want to take the selected element (in the event handler of the parent), and push it onto a **different** array **in the parent**. I am easily able to access/console.log the object that is being passed up during emission but in the **parent's** event-handling method, 
`this.currentlySelectedAdvertisements` (<--- the empty array I want to start filling up) is somehow no longer an array!

When I `console.log(this.currentlySelectedAdvertisements)` (as shown below) the console tells me it's **__ob__: Observer** <--- what is that? Why is it, that a property clearly defined as an array, is suddenly unusable when I need to mutate it in the event handler and alter how the children are rendered? Oddly enough, in the template, if I put `{{currentlySelectedAdvertisements}}` it shows an empty array `[]`. Also, in the event handling method of the parent, if I use `[].push.call(this.currentlySelectedAdvertsiements, payload.chosen)`, I am able to not get an error. However, I cannot seem to iterate through `this.currentlySelectedAdvertisements` and effect how children are rendered. I'm quite confounded by this, where did I go wrong? I am pretty new to Vue.js, and this is only the second project I have used it on. Please help me reach enlightenment/understanding.

**FULL info with code samples**

I have a **parent component** which has an array in it's `data` attribute like so

```
// **** PARENT COMPONENT JS ****
import Advertisement from './Advertisement.vue';

export default {
  name: 'Column2',
  data() {
    return {
      columns: 2,
      currentlySelectedAdvertisements: [] // <--- clearly defined as an Array
    };
  },
  props: { 
    adPool: Array,
    positions: Array
  },
  components: {
    'advertisement': Advertisement,
  },
  methods: {
    handleSelection(payload) { // <--- event handler method

      console.log("in column2 component and advert selected was ", payload);
      // this.currentlySelectedAdvertisements.push(payload.chosen);

      console.log(this.currentlySelectedAdvertisements);

      //  right here ^ now shows as '__ob__: Observer' in the console ****

    }
  }
};
```

I am using this array to render the **child component** `advertisement` like so (here is the template section)

```
<!-- *** PARENT COMPONENT TEMPLATE FOR RENDERING CHILD COMPONENTS *** -->
<template>
   <div class="column2">
      <div v-for="(ad, index) in currentlySelectedAdvertisements" class="column2__column">
         <advertisement :position="positions[index]" :adPool="adPool" :image="ad.image"></advertisement>
      </div>
      <div v-for="i in (columns - currentlySelectedAdvertisements.length)" class="column2__column column2__column--dashed">

         <advertisement @advertisement-selected="handleSelection" :position="positions[i-1]" :adPool="adPool"></advertisement>

     <!-- here is the listener ^ ****** -->

      </div>
   </div>
</template>
```

Now in the **child component** I have a select element that renders the user's choices to pick from (here is part of template)

```
 <!-- *** CHILD COMPONENT TEMPLATE *** -->
 <div class="advertisement__chooser">

    <select v-model="selected" @change="advertisementSelected(selected)" :name="ad_position">

     <!-- here is the change listener ^ for when the user picks an option ***** -->

      <option value="">Please Choose</option>
      <option v-for="ad in adPool" :data-img="ad.image" :value="ad.id">{{ad.name}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

And here are the methods that find the selected item, and **emit the event for the parent to listen to**

```
 // *** PART OF CHILD COMPONENT JS ***
 methods: {

  advertisementSelected(id, event) { // <--- event handler in child

    var chosen_advert = this.findAdById(id);
    var event_payload = {};
    if ( chosen_advert ) {
      event_payload = {
        position: this.ad_position,
        chosen: chosen_advert
      };
      console.log('In Advertisement.vue ', event_payload);

      this.$emit('advertisement-selected', event_payload);

      // and here ^ is the emission of the event ******

    }
  },
  findAdById(id) {
    for ( var i in this.adPool ) {
      if ( this.adPool[i].id === id ) {
        return this.adPool[i];
      }
    }
    return -1;
  }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of `console.log(this.currentlySelectedAdvertisements)` in the **parent's event handler** [screenshot](https://www.screencast.com/t/flDEGu6WgzHq)

Comment: All data values in Vue are converted to observed values. That's how Vue's reactivity works. Where is the `$on` defined?

Comment: Actually I guess it doesn't matter. It looks like the observed data value was correctly pushed into the array (though you have it commented out in the code).

Comment: ^ for whatever reason though, that commented out array push, throws a very strange error saying `invalid array length`, so that is what's weird about this, I can't push onto that array without using Array.prototype, and I can't iterate through the array and render child components with each iteration.

Comment: I don't think that's where the error is occurring. I think it's more likely occurring in your template logic. It would be helpful if you made a small demonstration of the issue in a fiddle/pen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so in the end, this somehow resolved itself....
I went home for the day, and when I came back and fired up the webpack dev server again this morning, no errors, no issues, it works exactly as I expected it to yesterday. I don't understand, and I'm pretty frustrated, but I'm just glad I wasn't losing my mind, and this works the way I want it to.